# Making UI in Tkinter. Running into problems

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a UI for a twitter scraping program that I've written in python. I'm including the code and am open to all suggestions.

```
import random
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry, StringVar, DISABLED, NORMAL, END, W, E

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Python Scraper")

        self.label = Label(master, text="Please enter a hashtag (#hashtag) to search twitter for.")
        self.label1.pack()

        #Box to input hashtag

        self.label2 = Label(master, text = "How many results would you like per search? Recommended: 200-1000.")
        self.label2.pack()

        #Box to enter results per search

        self.label3= Label(master, text = "How many times would you like Twitter scraped? Warning: do not exceed the data cap! Recommended 6 or less times")
        self.label3.pack()

        #box to enter number of times to scrape twitter

        self.label4 = Label(master, text = "What would you like on your x-axis?")
        self.label4.pack()

        #drop down box with the 5 options

        self.label5 = Label(master, text = "What would you like on your y-axis")
        self.label5.pack()

        #dropdown box with the same five options as above

        self.search_button = Button(master, text="Search", command=self.search)
        #self.search_button.pack()



    def search(self):

    #This should take the inputs from the boxes and selections from the x and y axis and 
    #enter it into another program that will be pasted below. I don't want to share due to 
    #OAuth credentials etc..
        print("Greetings!")

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm getting this error upon running this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkkkk2.py", line 32, in <module>
    my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
  File "tkkkk2.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.label1.pack()
AttributeError: MyFirstGUI instance has no attribute 'label1'
```

What I think is happening:
I think that I need to do something regarding the labels. I feel that tkinter is defaulted to deal with one label just fine, but that I need to do something to make another label.

next:
I have no idea how to make input boxes or pass these values to another funciton.
I'm on a macbook air running El Capitan, I have python 2.7.

Comment: Could it be a typo? `self.label = Label...` Maybe that should be `self.label1`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a pretty simple typo. You have these two lines:

```
self.label = Label(master, text="Please enter a hashtag (#hashtag) to search twitter for.")
self.label1.pack()
```

and I think the first line should look like this:

```
self.label1 = Label(master, text="Please enter a hashtag (#hashtag) to search twitter for.")
```

where we make `self.label` -> `self.label1`